# Category image above product title on single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display product category image above product title. Product category image is logo which company created this product.

Image for better understanding:
[image: Edited screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this code in the head of your body.

```
<?php
/**
 * Display category image on category archive
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_category_image', 2 );
function woocommerce_category_image() {
    if ( is_product_category() ){
        global $wp_query;
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        if ( $image ) {
            echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $cat->name . '" />';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

It looks like you're trying to put the category image in the top left of your *body* so I believe that you won't even need to add css to the code.

Post back the results and elaborate more if I misunderstood.

P.S. If some items are overlapping, play with CSS.

Comment: you are close. That posted image in shop for category: https://imgur.com/PekondC

I want code to check in which category is product then display this category image in product singe page template above product title: https://imgur.com/Oj5jHGO

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to add an element [category image] on top of the product title? Can you insert html in product title? Find where's the code for 'product / product title' and add html to manually set the image. If you want it to automatically link the according product category image to each products, you have to check your how your CMS/Framework handles the products, check documentation of said CMS/Framework.